# JBoss dropping connection after 30 min idle (Jboss XA Datasource with Oracle)

Tags: oracle, jdbc, jboss

I am using wildfly-8.2.0.Final with oracle 12c with ojdbc6. I have configured XA datasource to connect oracle database. Once server started and busy, everything looks fine, but if application server is idle for more than 30 min, i am getting below Exception:

Debug message:

> Failed on DataBaseConnectionMgr.createNewProperties()()  Reason code
>   subtext:   Exception message: java.sql.SQLException:
>   javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000457: Unchecked throwable in
>   managedConnectionReconnected()
>   cl=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@401c2dca[state=DESTROYED
>   managed
>   connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection@7a0249a7
>   connection handles=0 lastUse=1489587052205 trackByTx=false
>   pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool@4581a705
>   mcp=SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool@6887a22d[pool=jdbc/oracle/IMCTXDataSource]
>   xaResource=XAResourceWrapperImpl@3a0fa21c[xaResource=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnection@7a0249a7
>   pad=false overrideRmValue=false productName=Oracle
>   productVersion=Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release
>   12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and
>   Real Application Testing options
>   jndiName=java:jboss/datasources/IMCTXDataSource] txSync=null] 
>   Exception stack trace:
>     org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:154)
>     com.unisys.trans.shared.util.jdbc.DataBaseConnectionMngr.createNewProperties(DataBaseConnectionMngr.java:515)

```
<xa-pool>
    <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
    <max-pool-size>30</max-pool-size>
    <prefill>false</prefill>
    <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
    <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
    <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
    <no-tx-separate-pools>true</no-tx-separate-pools>
    <pad-xid>false</pad-xid>
    <wrap-xa-resource>true</wrap-xa-resource>
</xa-pool>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know  three mechanism to terminate idle connection.

1) Jboss idle-timeout-minutes. You don't set this and it's default value is 15 min. (the least probable)

2) Configuration in sqlnet.ora EXPIRE_TIME [sqlnet.ora expiretime](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETRF/sqlnet.htm#NETRF210)

3) Configuration of oracle db user profile. [create profile](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_6012.htm#SQLRF01310)

You have to check idle_time in profile configuration.

```
select * from dba_profiles where PROFILE = (SELECT profile FROM dba_users WHERE USERNAME =user);
```

Comment: i tried via Jboss idle-timeout-minutes. But it doesnt release the locks in DB, Am using Bitronix transaction manager.

Answer (score 0):

1# Recommended that to use below datasource connection validation mechanisms if not enabled:

```
<validation>
      <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
      <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker"></valid-connection-checker>
     <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"></exception-sorter>
</validation>
```

2#

```
<xa-pool>
      ...
     <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
      <no-tx-separate-pools />
</xa-pool>
```

3#flush-strategy = IdleConnections

4#use-fast-fail = true (immediately get a new physical connection)